# CocoonJS displays blank screen

Tags: android, mobile, screen, cocoonjs, impactjs

I'm using the ImpactJS framework for work and I've tried what most of people did to get their games to work but with no luck, most recently I tried following the instructions from this thread: http://impactjs.com/forums/help/cocoonjs/page/1.

It seems whatever I do CocoonJS refuses to launch the Impact framework (I've tried with both a game and with just the framework alone but nothing happens), whenever I launch the game I get a black screen running at about 60 fps.

Again I'm just trying to get the framework itself working but even that seems impossible. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have a javascript error (see console log), or maybe you have debug enabled on ImpactJS (debug requires DOM, not supported by CocoonJS)